# Sympy can't compute the integral

Tags: python, sympy, integral

I want to calculate this integration but sympy can't solve it:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import oo,pi,exp

q = 1.602176565*(10**(-19))     # Joule - Elektonvolt 
h = 4.135667516*(10**(-15))     # eV.s - Planck Constant
c = 299792458                   # m/s - Light Speed
k = 8.617343*(10**(-5))         # eV.K^-1 - Boltzmann Constant
Ts = 6000 #kelvin - heat of sun
sin2Qsun = 1/46000 # 

E = sp.Symbol('E')
integral_result = sp.integrate(E**2/(exp(E/(k*Ts))-1), (E, 1.12, oo))
print(integral_result)
```

```
Output: 
Integral(E**2/(exp(1.93408416801637*E) - 1), (E, 1.12, oo))
```

I have tried to use evalf() but it didn't work. 
If i delete `-1` in the parameter like this; `sp.integrate(E**2/(exp(E/(k*Ts)))` then it works: (i don't know why?)

```
Output: 
0.174655209356127
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sympy is primarily meant for symbolic calculations. For numerical calculations you might want to look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html